# Clearing Records in a Data Extension using SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

trying to clear the records in a DE using a query in Automation Studio but it's not clearing the data. Am I doing this wrong?

```
 SELECT Email
,[Activity 18 Digit ID]
,[Hidden Contact 18 Digit ID]   
 FROM [Recruitment Contacts Booking Attended]
 WHERE 1 = 0
```

Comment: Are you using *Overwrite* option in your query?

Comment: no am not, What would that look like, and should I be? thx for responding so quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating your Query Activity in Automation Studio, you want to select the Overwrite option in the step where you select your target data extension:
[image]
This will ensure that the empty result of your query will overwrite the records in the target data extension with 0 rows.

To avoid errors (as you are trying to read from same data extension as you are overwriting), you can use this smart trick, which [Adam Spriggs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) once taught me:

```
SELECT null as Email,
null as [Activity 18 Digit ID],
null as [Hidden Contact 18 Digit ID]
WHERE 1 = 0
```

Comment: when I switch it to overwrite I get an error:Error saving the Query field.Update Type must be 'Update' or the target data extension 'Recruitment Contacts Booking Attended' cannot appear in the query.

Comment: My bad - forgot to account for you are reading from same DE as you are overwriting. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Perfect, works great. thank you so much for your help. I saw that null syntax in another post but I didn't realize I needed to select overwrite